# Where QML camera.videoRecorder.record() save video file by default?

Tags: qml

Where QML camera.videoRecorder.record()  save video file by default  ?

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.0


Item {
    id:recoder
    width:640
    height:360

    property bool rstat:true

    function recordingSt(st)
    {
        if(st){
            camera.videoRecorder.record() ;
            st = false;
        }else{
                camera.videoRecorder.stop() ;
                st = true;
            }
    }



    MouseArea
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked:recordingSt(rstat)
    }

    Camera {
            id: camera
            videoRecorder.audioEncodingMode: CameraRecorder.ConstantBitrateEncoding
            videoRecorder.audioBitRate: 48000
            videoRecorder.mediaContainer: "mp4"
            videoRecorder.frameRate: 25
    }

    VideoOutput {
        source: camera
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus : visible // to receive focus and capture key events when visible
    }


}
```

I am using Win8 OS have no idea where the video goes and how to set the path for recording . I tried

```
videoRecorder.outputLocation: "sameDirectory"
```

still not working why ?

Comment: instead of setting st to false or true in the "recordingSt" function, it should be rstat. otherwise you are modifying a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation, it looks like you can set the location where you want to save by means of the properties `imageCapture`, which has the method `captureToLocation`.

It has also a property called `capturedImagePath` that maybe contains what you are looking for.

Look [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-cameracapture.html#capturedImagePath-prop) and [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-cameracapture.html) and [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-cameracapture.html#capturedImagePath-prop) for further details.

Sorry, just seen you were asking for the `videoRecording`.
It has the `actualLocation` property as well and it works as above, doesn't it?

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-camerarecorder.html#actualLocation-prop) states that that property holds the actual location of the last saved media content. Be aware that it's available once the recording starts, so you should look at it after the `record` method has been invoked.

Comment: it still not working for me , can not record a video